# QTP, Unspecified Error when calling a specific function

Tags: error-handling, vbscript, runtime-error, qtp

I'm facing a problem with QTP 11 (Quick Test Professional), the problem occurred when trying to call some function, QTP display a run time error ("General run error.") poopup message box.

i had tried many time to resolve the issue, but I dont understand what exactly causing the error.

when i Call a function from "Function library" the error displays. unless i took this function to an Action then the function will work.

have any one faced issue like this ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We definitely need more information if you want to know why QTP is spitting an error message at you. The "General run error" is the last resort error of QTP (like 'unhandled exception' in other languages but without the convenient stack trace), it could mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get the "General Run Error" error when I am attempting to call a function and pass the incorrect number of parameters in the function call.

Can you explain your last paragraph some more?  When you run the function via FL, it works?  You should not be running functions directly in your FL, but inside of your actions.

Here's an example:

**Action**

```
test_function("Hello", "42")
test_function(42, "Hello")
```

**Function Library**

```
Function test_function(sTextString, iIntNumber)
  iNewIntNumber = iIntNumber + 1
  MsgBox "String: " & sTextString & vbNewLine & "Int + 1: " & iNewIntNumber
End Function
```

In my function library, the second line (*iNewIntNumber = iNewIntNumber + 1*) may throw a "General Run Error" in the action due to an invalid cast on the variable.